# How can I programmatically detach a NIC from its VM in Azure ARM

Tags: azure-resource-manager

How can I programmatically detach a NIC from its VM in Azure ARM ?

Can someone please help with the URL that I need to post in order to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

There no API to detach, only remove the nic https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt163562.aspx.
a workaround would be to re-crate the VM (using the same disks as the original one) with the new vnet, nic,ips etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `Azure Resource Manager Templates` from the `azure-cli` or `PowerShell` to deploy, then you can simply use the deployment in `Incremental` mode and remove the `networkProfile` of the virtual machine. It should update the virtual machine to be detached from the old NIC.

Answer (score 0):

There is one to one relationship between VM to NIC.
There is no much benefit we will get for detach of NIC, So AzureRM provided the 
REST API to delete the NIC.

Below mentioned is the REST API Call for delete NIC :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt163562.aspx